# Cosine similarity is constantly 1.0

Tags: java, nlp, deeplearning4j

I am trying to build paragraph vectors and perform some inferences on them with the DeepLearning4J framework in Java. When I build my paragraph vectors into a ZIP folder, I am able to get similarities by using line numbers like so:

```
SentenceIterator sentenceIterator = new BasicLineIterator(new File(inputFilePath));
AbstractCache<VocabWord> abstractCache = new AbstractCache<VocabWord>();
TokenizerFactory tokenizerFactory = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();
tokenizerFactory.setTokenPreProcessor(new CommonPreprocessor());

LabelsSource labelsSource = new LabelsSource("LINE_");

ParagraphVectors paragraphVectors = new ParagraphVectors.Builder()
        .minWordFrequency(1)
        .iterations(5)
        .epochs(1)
        .layerSize(100)
        .learningRate(0.025)
        .labelsSource(labelsSource)
        .windowSize(5)
        .iterate(sentenceIterator)
        .trainWordVectors(false)
        .vocabCache(abstractCache)
        .tokenizerFactory(tokenizerFactory)
        .sampling(0)
         .build();
paragraphVectors.fit();

double similarity1 = paragraphVectors.similarity("LINE_9835", "LINE_100");
System.out.println("Similarity: " + similarity1);

WordVectorSerializer.writeParagraphVectors(paragraphVectors, outputParagraphVectorsFilePath);
```

The variable `inputFilePath` refers to the text document that contains some information. The variable `outputParagraphVectorsFilePath` refers to the location on the disk where the vectors are to be stored. This function works and the similarities are accurate. The problem occurs below:

```
TokenizerFactory tokenizerFactory = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();
tokenizerFactory.setTokenPreProcessor(new CommonPreprocessor());

ParagraphVectors paragraphVectors = WordVectorSerializer.readParagraphVectors(new File(inputFilePath));
paragraphVectors.setTokenizerFactory(tokenizerFactory);
paragraphVectors.getConfiguration().setIterations(1);

INDArray inferredVectorA = paragraphVectors.inferVector("This is my world .");
INDArray inferredVectorA2 = paragraphVectors.inferVector("This is my world .");
INDArray inferredVectorB = paragraphVectors.inferVector("This is my way .");


System.out.println("Cosine similarity A/B:" + Transforms.cosineSim(inferredVectorA, inferredVectorB));
System.out.println("Cosine similarity A/B2:" + Transforms.cosineSim(inferredVectorA, inferredVectorA2));
```

The `inputFilePath` variable refers to the location on disk where the ZIP folder is that contains the vectors. When I run this function, I get the following:

> `Cosine similarity A/B:1.0`
> `Cosine similarity A/B2:1.0`

Even if I change the vectors around and compare them to other vectors, I get the same 1.0. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/4881) issue posted on GitHub, the main reason why the cosine similarity was inaccurate was because of the incorrect versions used for `dl4j` and `nd4j`. The versions used in my project were `0.7.1`. After updating to `0.9.1`, I was able to get accurate answers. Here are some important guidelines:

1. **If you are downloading a complete project online:** Make sure you check the external libraries and ensure they are up to date. The best way to determine that is by regularly checking the DeepLearning4J website or by downloading new copies of the GutHib project available [here](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples)
2. **Ensure that you are using the correct file extensions:** After upgrading my project, I received a ZIP error because the paragraph vectors were supposed to be in a ZIP folder. I had them in a binary file